# I am trying to configure I3status and my memory bar is showing far more memory than actually in /proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux, archlinux, i3

**My status bar is showing:**

```
16777216.0 TiB free, 16777216.0 TiB Available, 179.4 MiB used
```

**/proc/meminfo contains:**

```
MemFree:   3612112kB

MemAvailable: 3612112kB

...

Cached 192248kB
```

**Lastly in my i3status config**

```
memory {

        format = "%free free, %available available, %used used"

}
```

Not my final config, but just not sure why I am getting funny output values on my status bar.

Comment: i3status had an overflow issue on 32 bit systems with 4gb ram like yours. It was fixed in [ad29f204](https://github.com/i3/i3status/commit/ad29f204b7a57cb43b1d0bc5502b1f9177a06ea9).